how to use \fp_use
an error occurred when I use \fp_use.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definevar}{m}
 {% #1 = comma separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be undefined
  \xcn_var_def:n {#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setvar}{m}
 {% #1 = comma separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be defined
  \xcn_var_set:n {#1}
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_new_variable:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set_variable:nn { V }

\keys_define:nn { xcn/var/def }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \fp_new_variable:V \l_keys_key_str
   \fp_set_variable:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1},
 }
\keys_define:nn { xcn/var/set }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \fp_set_variable:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1},
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_var_def:n { \keys_set:nn { xcn/var/def } {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_var_set:n { \keys_set:nn { xcn/var/set } {#1} }

\NewDocumentCommand{\fpset}{mm}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:c { l__XCN_ \token_to_str:N #1 _fp }
  \fp_set:cn { l__XCN_ \token_to_str:N #1 _fp } {#2}
  \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand #1 { }
    { \fp_use:c { l__XCN_ \token_to_str:N #1 _fp } }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}{ \fp_use:N #1 }  % where is the problem with this line

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\definevar{b=0.24,
           h=5.1,
           A=b*(b+h),
           I=b*(b+h)^3/12
          }

\usefpvar{A}

\end{document}


Still careless usage of \def? Using \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand amounts to the same. Anyway, you cannot do \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand A.

could you please resolve that ?

@XCN What do you mean 'resolve'? You cannot define letters in TeX (other than those that are set 'active') - you can only define macros.

replace  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}{ \fp_use:N #1 }   with  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}{ \fp_eval:n #1 }  .  \fp_eval works fine in this case. but I'm not sure if this is the best way .

@XCN don't leave commenst telling people to change teh question, if you want to ask about modified code, edit the question to make a better example, note also thet :n arguments should take a brace group so \fp_eval:n #1 should be \fp_eval:n {#1] unless you are absolutely certain there is ony ever one token here (and even then using braces would be better style)

@XCN No, of course I won't endorse your bad coding style.

that's all right.  thanks for your answer.

The title of this thread rhymes.

Let's see what your code actually does.
With
\definevar{
  b=0.24,
  h=5.1,
  A=b*(b+h),
  I=b*(b+h)^3/12
}

you're defining b, h, A and I for usage in fp-expressions.
Your definition of \usefpvar is completely wrong, because \fp_use:N expects an fp variable, something like l_<module>_<name>_fp and not a one-letter variable like the ones you're defining. You need nothing special, because
\fpeval{b}

would already return 0.24.
I won't comment your \fpset for the main reason that carelessly using \def is dangerous. And using \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand amounts to the same.

I know I misued \fp_use.  you mean \fpset is questionable as well ?

@XCN Didn't I say that I don't want to comment about \fpset? Yes, it's questionable for the reason I stated.

Don't forget that we have LuaTeX which has Lua interpreter build in. Your task can be solved without any expl3 code very simply using \directlua. For example using the \expr macro from OpTeX we can do
\directlua{
           b=0.24
           h=5.1
           A=b*(b+h)
           I=b*(b+h)^3/12
}

\expr{A}

\bye

and the result is 1.282.

that's true. I found it not easy to learn expl3. it's more complex than python and lua

I found that it is not easy to use expl3 because it switches to different than classical TeX terminology and the codes are very unclear for someone who knows TeX. So I don't use it.
